# Can't get jsPlumb to draw lines correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

http://jsbin.com/ofapew/1/edit
I'm trying to use jsPlumb to connect two points. (Those green dots, to the top of a black border box.)

The most perplexing thing is that you can see it is making a green dot end point to where the line should go, at the top of the black outlined box, but the line doesn't go there.

I thought it might be that the green dots are in a position absolute container, but that wasn't it. It still draws the line to the same point when I change that.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I needed the container specified.